# The complete bipartite graph K2,5 is planar

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, bipartite-graphs

I wonder why The complete bipartite graph K2,5 is planar?

Answer (score 5):

Just draw it out. The two high-degree vertices form one class together; the five low-degree vertices form the other.

[image: Complete graph on 2, 5 vertices]